# No homogenous, isotropic and static solutions for Einstein equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, cosmology, universe, fluid-statics

How can I prove that for a physical perfect fluid the Einstein equations possess no solutions that are homogeneous, everywhere isotropic and static?

Comment: You can look at galaxies -- non-interacting stars, bound by gravitation. The gravitation interaction goes from isotropic in the centre, to disk-like (anisotropic) further out. What happens when you do that with light? The interaction increases in strength as the light focuses from $4\pi$ steradians down to $0$ steradians. Now, do that with gravitation, and you have an explanation for the dark matter in the galaxies, walls, filaments, etc.

Comment: What tools do you have ? I mean, are you supposed to get books on General Relativity all by yourself and study them alone ? Or have you already got courses ? We can maybe help you to organise your knowledge in such a way that you find what is useful in order to answer this question. But out in the blue...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, could you provide some more detail on the exact problem you are attempting to solve? For example, are you allowing for a cosmological constant or not? Are there any restrictions on the equation of state for the perfect fluid (for example, does it need to have the form $p = w \rho$)? Are there any restriction on the spatial curvature?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you cannot. There exists a homogeneous, static and isotropic solution of Einstein field equations derived by Einstein himself in 1917. It is called Einstein's universe and has the metric
\begin{equation}
ds^2=c^2~dt^2-\frac{1}{1-r^2/S^2}~dr^2-r^2~d\Omega^2, \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Please look into the paper https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/83001/ , chapter 3.